# How do I increment a value in a table with the previous value in the table?

Tags: javascript, arrays, increment

I made a program that lets you type in your score, using JavaScript and HTML; this adds a new row to a table with the coherent scores.

I want to be able to use the same input fields to type in a new score which sums itself with the previous typed score. I can't seem to figure out how to store the previous typed score without it becoming the newly typed score.

I tried creating two different lists and placing the "previous scores" list globally, but it still ends up containing the same scores.

```
function list_of_scores() {
  var scores = ["1"];
  var count = 1;

  for (var i = 1; i <= number_players; i++) {
    var id = "score_" + count;
    var score = parseInt(document.getElementById(id).value);
    scores.push(score);
    count++;
  }

  return scores;
}

function table_func() {
  var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  var row = table.insertRow();

  var scores = list_of_scores();

  scores[0] = table_count_1;
  table_count_1++;

  for (var i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
    var cell = row.insertCell();
    cell.innerHTML = scores[i];
  }
}
```

Scores is a list of the typed in scores. I need to add each element of this list to a new list containing the second set of scores. The first element in the list is not a score, but represents the "Round" on the scoreboard.

Comment: You need to add more of your code to your post as well as sample data and expected results.

Comment: Please add more code other than just the for loop. It would be easier to understand.

Comment: how come your functions don't have parameters?

Answer (score 0):

```
//Event listener for submit button of your input field.
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",()=>{
    let input = document.getElementById("inputText").value;
    let table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var previousCell = table.rows[table.rows.length-1].innerText;
    var row = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    //if else statement sets previous cell value to 0 if previous cell returns NaN.
    if(isNaN(parseInt(previousCell))){
        previousCell = "0";
        let newVal = parseInt(previousCell) + parseInt(input);
        cell1.innerHTML = newVal.toString();
    }
    else{
        let newVal = parseInt(previousCell) + parseInt(input);
        cell1.innerHTML = newVal.toString();
    }
});
```

If all you want is for scores to be summed you could do something like this. All this code does is gets the value of the input field and previous cell, adds them and makes a new row with said value.